# Microsoft Word Interop : COMException

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, com, office-interop

I'm writing a program in c# that takes screenshots and pastes them against pre-defined bookmarks in a Microsoft Word template (.dot) file.

The code works fine on Microsoft Word 2007 but fails randomly on Microsoft Word 2016.

I'm doing this by the following line of code:

```
// wdoc is a word document object
// bookMarkName is pre-defined in the code
wdoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookMarkName).Range.Paste();
```

The code works perfectly on Word 2007, but when I run it on Word 2016, it works for some time and then fails at the above line, showing the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1066): Command failed at
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.Paste()
```

How to get it working for Word 2016?

Comment: i got many problems like you with micrsofot.office.interop. it's sometimes just not very stable. i got best experiences if i'm killign all word processes and then running the code. don't know if it will help for your problem

Comment: Thanks. I already did that.

Comment: This looks like an intermittent problem. These types (I find) are most tricky to resolve even with all the environment setup and all source code in hand. You're asking for help providing next to no information. I guess that's why you got downvoted.

Comment: @parvee: It is a very confusing problem, but I resolved it. I will list my answer below to help others with the same problem. Anyway, what more information should I have posted in order to make the question "correct"? In my opinion, if someone needs more info to answer it, they can ask for it, and they will get it. But they don't. Instead, they just down vote and don't even post a comment to say what was wrong. I think it would be best for people to have to post a reason for down voting anything. If you can't type a reason, you don't have one.

Comment: @Nvj: that feature request has been discussed to death on _Meta_, and consistently the response is that voting should be and shall be anonymous. My advice is not to worry about the odd downvote - if you post good questions and answers, you will come out with more upvotes than down.

Comment: @Nvj, unfortunately, some people seem to downvote around certain tags by some shallow criteria without stating a reason, and `com` seems to be one of them.  In my opinion, you could have provided an isolated working example that would trigger the error.  I usually don't bother to ask for details unless I think I can help, but I also don't downvote, I prefer to leave the question alone in case someone else in the community stands up with genuine interest in helping or that can directly answer due to experience with the same or very similar symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours on the web, I found a solution to the above problem, and a very simple one.

The obvious problem was that Word 2016 was not fully supporting the Interop libraries for Word 2007, which were used for development.

So, if you're making a program that uses Interop to interact with Microsoft Office applications, build the program with different Interop libraries for different versions. It would be better if the program automatically used Interop libraries installed on the target system, because that would make it independent of the version of Microsoft Office installed on a system, but, as far as I have searched on it, that is not currently possible.

And if you're wondering how you would download the Interop libraries for different versions of Microsoft Office, my advice would be to not do so, and instead, build the program separately for each version of MS Office (by building it on a system on which that version of MS Office is installed), and distribute your program separately for different versions of Office. This way, the user can choose to download the appropriate version of your program according to which version of MS Office is installed on his/her system